# Gradually reveal parts of an image where the mouse clicks

Tags: python, user-interface, image-processing, graphics

I want to produce a code that allows the user to click on an image, initially covered with an mask, to reveal its parts. I want every click in a region to reveal it gradually, i.e. the region clicked would be gradually unblurred.

The code I have now is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Function to update the mask with a hole where the mouse is clicked
def update_mask(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global mask, last_mask, mask_history

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        hole_size = 50                                           # Hole size 

        cv2.circle(mask, (x, y), hole_size, (255, 255, 255), -1)  # Reveal the region 
        mask_history.append(mask.copy())
    
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        if len(mask_history) > 1:                                # If there is at least one mask before the last change
            mask = mask_history[-2]                              # Restore the mask before the last change
            mask_history.pop()                                   # Remove the last mask from history
        else:
            mask = np.zeros_like(image)                          # If right click after first hole-> Reset the mask to black
            mask_history = []                                    # Clear the mask history
      

original = cv2.imread("image.png")
image = original.copy()


mask_color = (0, 0, 0)                                   # Black mask of the size of the image
mask = np.full_like(image, mask_color, dtype=np.uint8)
mask_history = []

# Create a window and set the mouse callback to update the mask
cv2.namedWindow('Result')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Result', update_mask)

while True:
     
    image_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image,mask) # Apply the mask to the image

    # Display the result
    cv2.imshow('Result', image_masked)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 27:  # Press 'Esc' to exit
        break
    

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works to reveal a circle of the image where the mouse is clicked. I would like to modify it so that every pixel is gradually unblurred based on the number of time it appeared in the circle of a mouse click.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: that's just a matter of you figuring out what you want, what bit of code will do that, and then writing it.

Comment: I want to modify this code so that instead of completely revealing the pixels in the region of a mouse click, each pixel would gradually be unblurred based on the number of times it appeared in the circle of a mouse click.